# Remove all duplicate lines from a text document

Tags: c#, string, duplicates

I' trying to remove all duplicate rows from small text document with 300 rows:

```
       string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("doc1.txt");
       File.WriteAllLines("doc1.txt", lines.Distinct().ToArray());
```

and this way:

```
        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(mypath).ToList();  
        File.WriteAllLines(mypath, lines.Distinct().ToArray());
```

but only some rows are removed, duplicates are still there, seems like in two cases, if duplicates is near to each other, or if too far form each other. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

all rows in lowercase without any punctuation, allowed only one white space between words and with trim for last and first space or punctuation in string.

So if I got two similar rows one after another this codes does not works for me, if one duplicate located after different string previous to its double, then works, and if duplicate is row 7 in order and is equal is row 287, does not works

Comment: Have you checked trailing/leading white-spaces?

Comment: If you don't want to consider leading and trailing whitespace, you can use `lines.Select(l => l.Trim()).Distinct().ToArray()`

Comment: I've created the following snipped to test what you are experiencing: `var lines = Enumerable.Range(1, 300).Select(i => "line " + i).ToArray();
lines[6] = lines[286] = "identical lines";
var distinctLines = lines.Distinct().ToArray();`. Based on what you have experienced, the `distinctLines` array would still have 300 items, but if you run the snippet you'll find it has only 299.

Comment: @botond.botos true now works, sorry I just didn't saw your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the lines aren't exactly the same, there might be leading/trailing white-spaces.

You can remove white-spaces by invoking the `Trim()` method on the `string` objects representing a line:

```
File.WriteAllLines("doc1.txt", lines.Select(line => line.Trim()).Distinct().ToArray());
```